# Clarification: Are Generative Adversarial Networks an alternative to MCMC sampling?

Tags: bayesian, deep-learning, markov-chain-montecarlo, generative-models

I have been reading the original Goodfellow, et. al. paper on Generative Adversarial Networks and the way that they can obtain estimates of the posterior distribution of a discriminative network or autoencoder. Now usually something that generates estimates from the posterior involves either an MCMC sampling scheme, or in some cases conjugacy of the prior.

So I was wondering if someone could clarify whether GANs can act as a replacement for MCMC sampling, or are there areas which only MCMC will work?

Comment: MCMC is a simulation method to approximate a Bayesian posterior distribution and if needed Bayes estimates. GANs are a form of (point) parameter estimation that can be produced by MCMC algorithms. It thus makes little sense to put MCMC and GANs at the same level.

Comment: @Xi'an thanks for the info. Yeah, this is what was confusing me. So if I have a bayesian model, I can use MCMC to obtain the posterior distribution and then get a point/parameter estimate. If I read your message correctly, a GAN just provides a point estimate. I am still not clear on the difference? Do you mean that GANs can provide a point estimate, but not the full distribution? Can you recommend a reference that lays out the guarantees of GANs or the mathematical details? The original Goodfellow paper is a bit thin on the actual math.

Comment: You can check [Saatchi's and Wilson's Bayesian GANs.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09558)

Comment: @Xi'an I'm a bit surprised that an expert of your standing would recommend that paper. The resulting model is conceptually flawed (incompatible conditionals) and the results are terrible (mode collapse all the way, low image quality, etc.). Unsurprisingly, even in a field which is not overly selective in terms of quality, that paper has received few citations, and excluding those from collaborators of the authors, most citations criticize their approach.

Comment: @DeltaIV: Thanks, I have [commented this paper,](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2018/06/26/bayesian-gan-gan-style/) which, as you mentioned, is suffering from handling incompatible conditionals. Dan Roy (Toronto) also commented on that aspect earlier, when the paper was first arXived. This is however the only paper I have read on the topic.

Comment: @Xi'an then allow me to present you a considerably superior paper: http://people.csail.mit.edu/hehaodele/projects/TADGM2018-BayesGAN/paper.pdf

Comment: [MH-GAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.11357) seems to be a neat way combine GANs and MCMC -- where MCMC is used to obtain a distribution not over model parameters, but rather on generated samples

Answer (score 3):

Both Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) and the generator network from a Generative Adversarial Network (GAN) return samples from a probability distribution.

However, they solve different problems:

**MCMC** works when known the formula for the probability of each configuration (it does not need to be normalized). A classic example is an [Ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model), in which the probability of a configuration is $\exp(- \beta E)$, where $\beta$ is inverse temperature. To sample, we can use the [Metropolis-Hasting MCMC algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model#Metropolis_algorithm) - flipping a single spin, with probability related to energies of the states. MCMC is often being used for integration in Bayesian statistics. In principle (given infinite time) we always get the exact numerical result.

In **GANs** we do not know the probability distribution. Instead, we know a few samples from which we want to create a sampler from this probability distribution. We don't get a function that says what is the probability of a given sample (at least, not with typical discriminator network that does only guess if the sample is real or generated).
Furthermore, in the case of GANs the problem is fuzzy - the function depends on the neural network architecture, training process, and other factors. In general, there are infinitely many ways to turn a discrete set of samples into a probability distribution (sampler).

GANs and MCMC are not exclusive. As already pointed out by @shimao, you can combine both of the approaches as in [Metropolis-Hastings Generative Adversarial Networks (2018)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.11357).

Also, there is an overlap of functionality, for which either can be used. For example, patterns can be generated either with GANs or with MCMC ([here are some beautiful examples with ConvChain](https://github.com/mxgmn/ConvChain)). In the later, we typically it is more reliable and less data-hungry, but we need to translate input into probability (based on some assumptions).